# Why is my .png file not showing up

Tags: css, image

For some reason (which I can't seem to find), my .png image is not showing up.

I am trying to load it on the website through my CSS file and not as eg. `<img src="images/Balloon_1.png">`

```
<section id="container_1">
    <header id="header_container_1">
        <h1><a name="Over ons"></a>Over ons</h1>
   </header>
   <div id="Balloon_1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#Balloon_1{
     background: url(images/Balloon1.png);
     display: block;
     height: 70px;
     width: 64px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged the requests going over the wire?

Comment: this is a path problem. you have to provide path to image **relative** to your css file.

Comment: Try `background: url(../images/Balloon1.png);`

Comment: Yes. Bear in mind that url paths in the CSS file are relative to the location of the *CSS* file. Also, the best way of figuring out what's going on is to learn to use your browser's developer tools. They'll save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: @ Rowland: What do you mean by debugging?

@ Michal: Yes, thats what I thought as well and I changed the path several times. I also reshuffeld the file within the folders and tried  loading it again.

@ Vucko: Thx but not working either.

Comment: you are missing the `_` in the filename..

Comment: @ Matt, aware of the relativeness. I checked it with the developer tool on Chrome several times.

Comment: @ Gaby: No I am not. The name of the file is: Balloon1.png

Comment: @brain, ok.. the `img` example has a `_` and got me confused.. Can you post the file structure ?

Comment: It's cause that's the `ID` @GabyakaG.Petrioli, not the `src`.

Comment: @Brain - Please give me the `png` image, or edit your post with it, and I will throw a live version on my server for ya to show you it works.

Comment: @NicholasHazel i was talking about the `img` example..

Comment: Can you please just provide the `png` in question? I will give you a `live` version. And I'm a graphic designer, so I'm sure I can probably figure out some weird bug if it's file related.

Comment: [Works Fine With Your Structure](http://sinsysonline.com/makeitrain/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Works fine...?

**You have some sort of linking problem:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/SeC6W/

**HTML**

```
    <section id="container_1">
    <header id="header_container_1">
            <h1><a name="Over ons"></a>Over ons</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="Balloon_1"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Balloon_1 {
    background:url(http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}
```

**With your current code, please ensure your `.png` images resides *exactly* like this.**

`Index.html file root -> Images Folder -> Balloon1.png`

And your `CSS` file is linking to the image as such:

`../../images/Balloon1.png`

## Final answer for you.

You have an `assets` folder, so you had to `drop back twice`. By just doing `../` you were only going back to your `assets` folder, not your `root`.

`Root` is where your `index.html` lies.

`Root -> Assets -> CSS -> Style.css` is where your `style.css` lies.

`Root -> Images -> Balloon1.png` is where your `image` lies.

So, because your `CSS` file is deeper in the tree, you have to backtrack **twice** to get back to your `Root`.

`Root -> Assets`

`Root`

Then you can progress to...

`Root -> Images -> File`.

Comment: I just uploaded a new pic in the question section. Hopefully this clears it up.

Comment: @ Nicholas, I am new on Stackoverflow. How can I send you the .png file?

And it is not .PNG ,, it is .png
My scc is not running instyle. 
I hope the new image which I posted in the question section clears it up now.

Comment: Why does it need a ../../ in order to work? 
I still don't get that.

Comment: btw, for future reference. I was just saying upload your `.png` as an image, just like you did with the other one. I could have just downloaded it directly from the page. The only direct file transfers have to be done through `chat`, which is a mode where you can 1on1 chat with somebody if the comments get too long.

Answer (score 3):

Before providing an answer; some advice. Good coding standards designate that if Balloon1 is a design element for the page then yes you should load it as a background through CSS. If it's simply an image on the page that doesn't contribute to the site layout then you should continue to load it as an img tag.

Now I'll elaborate on the answers others have given you.

```
background: url(images/Balloon1.png);
```

is a file path relative to where this code is in a file. So if you have a CSS file in a folder called style, then this is looking for Balloon1.png in style/images/Baloon1.png.

```
background: url(/images/Balloon1.png);
```

in this example, leading with a forward slash '/' indicates that the path should begin in the root directory of your site. The root directory is your main folder, the lowest case denominator.

```
background: url(../images/Balloon1.png);
```

In this example the two periods are used to tell the path to start in the parent directory of wherever your file is. So again if you have a CSS file in a folder called style, then this is looking for Balloon1.png in whateverFolderStyleIsIn/images/Baloon1.png. You can combine this technique to back out of multiple files to start where you want using ../../images/Balloon1.png and so forth.

```
background: url(http://YourURL.com/images/Balloon1.png);
```

In this example the link is no longer relative and is direct. It points directly to your image file, but has the unfortunate effect of making your code only apply to that URL, you wouldn't be able to copy and paste this code to a different site without rewriting the direct url.

Comment: I offered to take his file and throw it live as proof lol. The direct path was the easiest way to show him it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe too late, and may not be very much relevant, but it is really helpful and saves me a lot of headache. There is an extension available for VS Code called `Path Intellisense` , whenever you type `./` or `../` in your code, the intellisense dropdown will show you the paths and folders. This really makes life easy and the worries of getting lost in wrong paths is over. 
Here's the link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense